# Radio button and drop down list command to create register form

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

In this code, cp.sex=i select individual radio button, and cp.product= dropdownlist1.selected item i gave but it shows an error. let any one tell, which code i given to  DOB, Product.

```
    Com_psi cp = new Com_psi();
    DAL_psi dp = new DAL_psi();
    cp.Psiid = int.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
    cp.Name=TextBox2.Text;
    cp.DOB = int.Parse(TextBox3.Text);
    cp.Sex = RadioButton1.
    cp.Mobile = int.Parse(TextBox4.Text);
    cp.Address = TextBox5.Text;
    cp.Product = DropDownList1.SelectedItem;
    cp.Amount = int.Parse(TextBox6.Text);
    int result = dp.insertpsi(cp);

    public int Psiid { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int DOB { get; set; }
    public string Sex { get; set; }
    public int Mobile { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
```

Comment: what code i give in cp.sex= ?,cp.product=?,

Comment: what is value of `RadioButton1` is it male or female?

Comment: above cp.name=Textbox2.Text; its valid,i dont know what code i give this below two items

Comment: can you show us your class `Com_psi`?

Comment: This is problem: `cp.Sex = RadioButton1.` And, really, this is problem too: `cp.Mobile = int.Parse(TextBox4.Text);`; and this: `cp.Amount = int.Parse(TextBox6.Text);` and this: `cp.DOB = int.Parse(TextBox3.Text);`

Comment: ok how i solve..what code i give

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  [Conditinal Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) to check wether RadioButton is checked or not.
if it is checked you assign the "Male" if it is not checked you can assign "Female".

**Solution 1 :** if `RadioButton1` value is `Male`

```
cp.Sex = (RadioButton1.Checked)?"Male":"FeMale";
```

**Solution 2:** if `RadioButton1` value is `FeMale`

```
cp.Sex = (RadioButton1.Checked)?"FeMale":"Male";
```

it is equalent to :

```
if(RadioButton1.Checked==true)
{
cp.Sex = "Male";
}
else
{
cp.Sex="FeMale";
}
```

**Solution 3 :** For DropdownList you can use `DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value`

Try This:

```
cp.Product = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;
```

Comment: i type this code its valid plz tell me dropdown list...code

Comment: @DownVoter: would be glad if you could improve this code.

Comment: ok sure..i am new to developing so how to learn c#.net...give any tips to me

Comment: @rakulrc: read c#.net books for ex: http://www.amazon.com/dp/1430242337/?tag=stackoverfl08-20 , and particioate in forums like Stackoverflow to see how others are posting answers.if you want you can reach me @  => `sudhakar.tillapudi@gmail.com` , allthe best